# Как убрать лишние нули JS

Tags: javascript, числа

При записи числа с лишними нулями результат получается неожиданным:

```js
let i = 000042;
console.log(i);   // 34
```

причем разные числа уменьшаются на разные значения. 
Как это можно поправить?

Comment: 1) Не записывать числа с ведущими нулями. 2) Если все-таки очень хочется, то `let i = parseInt('000042', 10);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

> Leading 0 (zero) on an integer literal, or leading
>   0o (or 0O) indicates it is in octal. Octal integers can include only
>   the digits 0-7.

То есть

> Ноль (или 0о, или 0О) в начале записи числа указывает на то, что число записано в восьмеричном виде.

Откуда в Вашем javascript-е берутся числа в такой записи?

Comment: В моём javascript-e таких чисел нет. А вообще вопрос я вырвал из контекста задачи с codewars