# Искажение данных в JS функции (razorpage, asp.net core 3.0)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Существует метод контроллера:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string code, string status)
{
   ViewBag.Code = code;
   ViewBag.Status = status;
   return View();
}
```

Во View для Foo переменная `code` передается корректно, далее происходит вызов функции JS:

```
<script>
  $(function () 
    { 
          function GetDataTable(serviceCode, statusCode)
          {
              console.log(serviceCode); //тут значение искажено (и почему-то пропадают нули в строке слева)
          }
 GetDataTable(@ViewBag.Code, @ViewBag.Status); // на этом этапе значения корректны
 })
</script>
```

Вишенка во всем этом - то, что некоторые значения обрабатываются корректно, а некоторые нет, пример :

- На входе во View - "00803007", в console.log() - "803007"
- На входе во View - "00403010", в console.log() - "132616"
- На входе во View - "02303010", в console.log() - "624136"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822684/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в рендеринге значений.
На готовой странице создавалась функция GetDataTable(00803007, 0), значения которой JS, видимо, воспринял как int.
Решилось добавлением апострофов до рендеринга:

```
GetDataTable('@ViewBag.Code', '@ViewBag.Status');
```

Функция после рендеринга:

```
GetDataTable('00803007', '0')
```